# How to prevent re-post caused by pressing browser refresh in ASP classic

Tags: asp-classic

I am new in ASP.

I have a submit.asp page => thankyou.asp page. when pressing browser refresh, it reload and re-send a new data submissions. It caused me getting a lot of multiple submission.

I'm trying to add this in, its work , but little problem still when pressing the leaving button , thankyou.asp page refresh and loading a fresh new entry.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

      window.onbeforeunload = function() {
      return "You are leaving now! See you again !";
      }

    </script>
```

I'm asking for help on how to redirect to another page when browser refresh.

Thanks!

Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Faisal says, redirecting back to the same page will prevent the form resubmitting on refresh.

This can be done in the following way:

```
<%
If Request.Form("submit") <> "" Then

    'form processing goes here

    Response.Redirect "thankyou.asp"
End If
%>
```

Where `"submit"` in `Request.Form("submit")` relates to the `name` attribute of

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!" />
```

in submit.asp

Comment: Thanks for your coding. will try out then. will let you know the result.

Answer (score 4):

Change it so if the user submits, you process the form, then *redirect* back to the page itself. This way when the user refreshes, it won't submit the form again

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It is possible to provide any coding? I'm new in ASP.

Comment: Just to add, this is called the "PRG" pattern (POST, Redirect, GET) if the OP is interested in researching this more.